# MediaWiki 1.22 Math Extension

Tags: mediawiki, mathjax, mediawiki-extensions

I am facing a problem to download and configure the MediaWiki's [Math](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Math) extension.

The problem is that the version i am using is the MediaWiki 1.22.6 and the extension's versions avaliable to download [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ExtensionDistributor/Math) starts at 1.23. Nevertheless, i discovered that the Math extension can be installed since the MW 1.19 but i cannot find this version.

However, the only thing i found was the [MathJax](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MathJax) that seems to be able to run under the MW 1.22, but i am not sure if the MathJax depends on the Math extension to run.

So my question is, how can add formulas in the MW 1.22? Is it through Math extension or i can use only the MathJax? If the Math extension is necessary, where can i find a version capable of run in the MW 1.22?

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: I Tried to install the Math extension 1.23 and, as expected, it did not work.

Comment: MathJax does not require the math extension (though the math extension relies on MathJax since v2).

Comment: 1.22 is not supported anymore and thus not offered for download. You can check it out from git if you want ([REL1_22](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-Math/tree/REL1_22)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For formulas in MediaWiki don't use the  Math extension or MathJax, instead use [Extension:SimpleMathJax](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SimpleMathJax).